# Managing number of authors shown in a citation

Tags: bibtex, author-number

I'm using `\bibliographystyle{phil_review}` and when I cite a paper with more than two authors it automatically appears as 'XX et. al.' What's the simplest way to control for the number of authors required before this happens?

Comment: Suppose I want to impose 'et.al' when there are at least four authors.

Comment: Thanks for this information. Could you indicate from where you've obtained your copy of the file `phil_review.bst`? It doesn't seem to be on the CTAN. I found one version on a GitHub website, but that version has some severe errors.

Comment: Here is where it can be found:http://tedsider.org/latex/phil_review.bst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to make BibTeX show the names of all authors (or editors) as long as there are no more than 3 authors, you'll need to edit the function `format.lab.names` in the file `phil_review.bst` along the following lines:

- Make a copy of the file and name it, say, `phil_review_mod.bst`. (Don't edit an original file.)
- Open the file `phil_review_mod.bst` in your favorite text editor and locate the function `format.lab.names`. (It starts on line 1286 in my copy of the file.)
- Delete the entire function -- it occupies about 23 lines of code -- and replace it with the following code:

  ```
  FUNCTION {format.lab.names}
  {'s :=
   "" 't :=
    #1 'nameptr :=
    s num.names$ 'numnames :=
    numnames 'namesleft :=
      { namesleft #0 > }
      { s nameptr
        "{vv~}{ll}" format.name$
        't :=
        nameptr #1 >
          {
            nameptr #2 =
            numnames #3 > and
              { "others" 't :=
                #1 'namesleft := }
              'skip$
            if$
            namesleft #1 >
              { ", " * t * }
              {
                s nameptr "{ll}" format.name$ duplicate$ "others" =
                  { 't := }
                  { pop$ }
                if$
                t "others" =
                  {
                    " " * bbl.etal *
                  }
                  {
                    numnames #2 >
                      { "," * }
                      'skip$
                    if$
                    bbl.and
                    space.word * t *
                  }
                if$
              }
            if$
          }
          't
        if$
        nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
        namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
      }
    while$
  }
  ```
- Save the file, either in the directory with your main `.tex` file or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution, and start using it by issuing the command `\bibliographystyle{phil_review_mod}`. Happy BibTeXing!